# Two forms conflict

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

In update user form, I want to split password from rest of the form.

In user model I validate it.

I want to have

form 1

```
  User infos fields
```

form 2

```
password and confirm fields.
```

in php I would do something like if post password is empty, ignore it.

is there something like

```
if :password 
    do validation
end
```

I need the model part, I have the rest.

just need an idea how to split validation in model or how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope i did understand you

```
class User << AR
  validates :password, 
     :lenght => {:between => 3..20}, 
     :confirmation => true,
     :if => Proc.new { self.password }
end
```

Comment: Maybe to simplify it: if I leave password empty where I update my info, dont update password to blank.

Comment: Yes, but thats the same as my answer (in another structure and with validation of the confirmation). But be aware, your posted solution doesn't validate your password if the password is blank! (So a user can update his account with a passwort == "" !)

Comment: Updated my post (validates now the confirmation, and i removed the validates presence -> presence is already checked by the length validation)